# How do Goliath enemies work?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

[image: Goliath, Meet David - Allowed a Goliath to level up four times before killing him]

There is an Achievement for "Goliath, Meet David - Allowed a Goliath to level up four times before killing him" but I don't know how Goliaths work to figure out how to do this.

When I've come across them before, they seem to attack me until I behead them, then some weird shrunken head atop of stringy neck comes out and they start rushing towards their friends (my enemies) and attack them until there's none left.

So how and why does this happens, and what are the actual Goliath AI rules? How do they "level up"?

Comment: Note you don't actually decapitate them, you knock off their helmet exposing their freakishly little head. They then get so mad their skull jumps out of their mouth. If you inspect them after they Rage you can see their head's skin on their corpse.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you knock off a [Goliath's](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Goliath) helmet and the little terrifying David Lynch head comes out, they go berserk and attack everyone.  They level up by killing their former allies.

> Upon killing enemies, the Goliath will gain experience points and gain levels, becoming even more dangerous. A beneficial aspect of this is that the dropped loot will be better. At the GOD ith level, drops are greatly increased.

An easy way to tell whether or not you've gotten it to a high enough level for the "Goliath, Meet David" achievement is if the Goliath has God in its name.

Comment: As a side note, if you level up a Midget Goliath he becomes a `Giant Midget Ultimate Badass Goliath` and gives extra loot, but does not give you the achievement :)

Comment: I was wrong about the title, he was simply a `Giant Midget of Death`. There's plenty of other goliath titles out there too, such as `Hulking Mass of Destruction`, but only the ones named `GOD-liath` counts towards the achievement.

Comment: Another side note, according to the wiki, "the experience points from the enemies he killed are tripled and added to his own"

Answer (score 7):

When you shoot off their helmets they start to Rage. You have a few seconds to kill them (don't, if you want the achievement) and then they turn into Raging Goliaths (their health refills too). Raging Goliaths will kill anything near them, **including allies**. Stop shooting him once he starts raging and he should ignore you and go for whoever's closest.

Piss off a Goliath who's with a bunch of buddies from a long range; he'll start slaughtering them. You can wound his buddies to help him, but don't kill them. He'll kill normal Bandits with ease, but you might want to soften up Badasses for him.

As he kills them he'll power up and turn into a Baddass, then Super, then God Raging Goliath and get larger each time. **He'll need to kill 10 enemies** (your enemies, his friends) to get to max level, he'll always be called a God at that point.

Note they're *much* tougher after they've leveled up, but they drop accordingly better loot, particularly at God level.

Comment: Do the Loot Goon Goliath's chests contain better loot if they've been leveled?

Comment: @Fambida We tried this on the Loot Goon Goliath in Frostburn Canyon. He leveled up and all, and I think the loot he dropped on death was good (got a purple). But the loot in the weapons locker on his back was standard green stuff. So I don't think the Loot Goon Goliaths' leveling matter more than regular Goliaths. It could have been coincidence though. Will need to experiment more.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just wait for him to flash yellow four times, and then kill him if you want the achievement.