# Does the loot from the loot Goliath improve if he levels up before dying?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Goliath enemies work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/how-do-goliath-enemies-work)

The question says it all.   I have tried this a few times but I didn't get any conclusive results.  If I let the loot Goliath destroy all of his 'friends' to level up, does the loot on his back improve once I kill him?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - I don't think so as I am asking specifically about the Loot goliaths and about the loot only dropped from the chest on their backs.

Comment: The loot from the goliath itself would increase, therefore making it fairly pointless to rely on the chest for loot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loot from the chest will be the same as a chest found in the level regardless of the goliath's level.

The goliath itself will drop better loot upon dying if it leveled.

Source: leveled loot goliathes a couple times